Spring property based on 2 profiles
I'm trying to create spring property that is dependant on 2 profiles.
Some background: we have a number of microservices that migrate from auth mechanisms based on legacy custom auth service to keycloak. These services work in dev, test, prod environments. We configured another new k8s cluster (cluster #2) for keycloak based services and services that use legacy auth service live in old k8s cluster (cluster #1).
So the issue is that I would like to specify properties for legacy profile (url to legacy auth service and others) and keycloak profile (for instance spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri and others). Also I need these properties be different for each environment (dev, test, prod).
It looks like I can declare both legacy and keycloak properties for each environment but this leads to redundant beans to be created.
Is there any way to solve it with Spring? (Besides manual condition bean setup for keycloak based on some custom properties)

Without seeing your code it's difficult to provide a solution. Do you programmatically declare your legacy authentication scheme or use properties exclusively? Does your SecurityFilterChain initialization change based on the authentication strategy chosen? If the answer to either of these is 'yes' then you probably need to use some sort of @ConditionalOnProperty or @Profile mechanism.

You can define different Configuration classes for your legacy properties and keycloak properties and use @Profile annotation to control which class is used.
For example,
@Configuration
@Profile({"legacy-dev"})
public class LegacyDevConfiguration {
    // ...
}

@Configuration
@Profile({"legacy-test"})
public class LegacyTestConfiguration {
    // ...
}

// etc etc

@Configuration
@Profile({"keycloak-prod"})
public class KeycloakProdConfiguration {

}

You can also use the @ConditionalOnProperty annotation to only create beans conditionally based on the presence and value of a configuration property.
For example
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "keycloak" name = "enabled")
public KeycloakBean keycloakBean() {
    return new KeycloakBean();
}

and the bean is created if the keycloak.enabled property is available in your properties file for that environment.
